# Creating a LINQ Expression where parameter equals object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Given a primitive value `age` I know how to create an expression like this:

```
//assuming: age is an int or some other primitive type
employee => employee.Age == age
```

By doing this:

```
var entityType = typeof(Employee);
var propertyName = "Age";
int age = 30;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName),
            Expression.Constant(age)
        )                    
    , parameter);
```

That works fine except in scenarios where the property and constant in question are not primitive types.

How would I construct a similar expression if the comparison is between objects?

With EF I can just write:

```
Location location = GetCurrentLocation();
employees = DataContext.Employees.Where(e => e.Location == location);
```

**That also works**, but if I try to create the same expression:

```
var entityType = typeof(Employee);
var propertyName = "Location";
var location = GetCurrentLocation();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName),
            Expression.Constant(location)
        )                    
    , parameter);
```

I get an error that says:

`Unable to create a constant value of type 'Location'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

My suspicion is that `Expression.Constant()` only expects primitive types, so I need to use a different expression factory method. (maype `Expression.Object`? - I know that doesn't exist)

Is there a way to create an expression that compares objects? Why is that EF is able to interpret it correctly if its a compiled LINQ statement, but not when it is an expression?

Comment: Just as a side note, using Expression.Constant forces the database server to generate a new SQL execution plan every time the constant changes. This can have a large performance impact, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845097/rewriting-a-linq-expression-query-to-enable-caching-sql-execution-plan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what has been mentioned in previous answers. A more specific solution would go as such:

```
public static Expression CreateExpression<T>(string propertyName, object valueToCompare)
{
    // get the type of entity
    var entityType = typeof(T);
    // get the type of the value object
    var valueType = valueToCompare.GetType();
    var entityProperty = entityType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    var propertyType = entityProperty.PropertyType;


    // Expression: "entity"
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "entity");

    // check if the property type is a value type
    // only value types work 
    if (propertyType.IsValueType || propertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
    {
        // Expression: entity.Property == value
        return Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(parameter, entityProperty),
            Expression.Constant(valueToCompare)
        );
    }
    // if not, then use the key
    else
    {
        // get the key property
        var keyProperty = propertyType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Length > 0);

        // Expression: entity.Property.Key == value.Key
        return Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(
                Expression.Property(parameter, entityProperty),
                keyProperty
            ),
            Expression.Constant(
                keyProperty.GetValue(valueToCompare),
                keyProperty.PropertyType
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT POINTS :**

1. Make sure to check for nulls
2. Make sure `propertyType` and `valueType` are compatible (either they are the same type or are convertible)
3. Several assumptions are made here (e.g. that you do assign a `KeyAttribute`)
4. This code is not tested, so it is not exactly copy/paste ready.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what is `otherProperty`

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that because EF doesn't know how to translate equality comparisons on `Location` into a SQL expression.

However, if you know what properties of `Location` you want to compare, you can do this with anonymous types:

```
var location = GetCurrentLocation();
var locationObj = new { location.LocationName, location.LocationDescription };
employees = DataContext.Employees.Where(e => new { e.Location.LocationName, e.Location.Description } == locationObj);
```

Of course that's equivalent to:

```
var location = GetCurrentLocation();
employees = DataContext.Employees.Where(e => e.Location.LocationName == location.Name && 
                                             e.Location.Description == location.Description);
```

Comment: What confuses me is that `employees = DataContext.Employees.Where(e => e.Location == location);` **works** if I write it out directly like that, but if I try to create an identical expression, it doesn't work. Does the compiler do something extra that can't be done at runtime?

Comment: The compiler is doing a lot less than the run-time. It's just checking to see if the types are compatible in C# for this expression. At run-time EF actually has to convert the expression to a SQL query, which is much more difficult. You're seeing the error at run-time and not at compile time because the compiler doesn't know the expression can't be converted.

Comment: I'm also not sure if I made myself clear, but I updated the question in the hope of providing additional clarity.

Comment: @p.s.w.g The first snippet won't work with EF because it only supports primitive types in comparisons. Linq to Sql is ahead of EF here. But daptia, what is said here is the root of your problem. Whatever expression you will build, in the end EF will have to be able to translate it into SQL. You must build the equivalent of `Where(e => e.Location.Id == location.Id)`.

Answer (score 2):

Give the code below a run. I wanted to test your assumption that e => e.Location == location is compiling into something that can be constructed with Expression.Equal, Expression.Property, and Expression.Constant.

```
    class Program {
       static void Main(string[] args) {
          var location = new Location();
          Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> expression = e => e.Location == location;

          var untypedBody = expression.Body;

          //The untyped body is a BinaryExpression
           Debug.Assert(
              typeof(BinaryExpression).IsAssignableFrom(untypedBody.GetType()), 
              "Not Expression.Equal");

           var body = (BinaryExpression)untypedBody;
           var untypedLeft = body.Left;
           var untypedRight = body.Right;

           //The untyped left expression is a MemberExpression
           Debug.Assert(
              typeof(MemberExpression).IsAssignableFrom(untypedLeft.GetType()), 
              "Not Expression.Property");

           ////The untyped right expression is a ConstantExpression
          //Debug.Assert(
          //   typeof(ConstantExpression).IsAssignableFrom(untypedRight.GetType()),                 
          //   "Not Expression.Constant");

          //The untyped right expression is a MemberExpression?
          Debug.Assert(
               typeof(MemberExpression).IsAssignableFrom(untypedRight.GetType())));
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location { }
```

It seems like it isn't, and its because the right expression isn't a Constant. To see this, uncomment the commented out code.

What I don't understand is why the right expression is a MemberExpression. Perhaps someone who knows the linq expression compiler can shed more light onto this then I can.

Edit: This may have to do with closure in lambdas - a class is created behind the scenes which contains the closed over variables. The location might then be a member of that class. I'm not sure about this, but it's what I suspect.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991621/can-i-capture-a-local-variable-into-a-linq-expression-as-a-constant-rather-than) may shed additional light on the situation.

Comment: Great! You sir understood my problem! An I think we're heading in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to hear it. The link I just added suggested 1) that captured variables cannot be added to linq expressions in the runtime, and 2) the LinqKit might be able to help. I didn't do an in depth read, but I think you might appreciate the discussion.