# Rewriting a LINQ Expression query to enable caching SQL Execution Plan

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

While reading an article on [Entity Framework performance](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it), I came across this piece of information:

> Secondly, the problem **[SQL Server won’t reuse the execution plan]** occurs in the first place because (due to an implementation detail) when passing an int to the Skip() and Take() methods, Entity Framework can’t see whether they were passed absolute values like Take(100), or a variable like Take(resultsPerPage), so it doesn’t know whether the value should be parameterized.

The proposed solution is to change this style of code:

```
var schools = db.Schools
    .OrderBy(s => s.PostalZipCode)
    .Skip(model.Page * model.ResultsPerPage)
    .Take(model.ResultsPerPage)
    .ToList();
```

In to this style:

```
int resultsToSkip = model.Page * model.ResultsPerPage;
var schools = db.Schools
    .OrderBy(s => s.PostalZipCode)
    .Skip(() => resultsToSkip) //must pre-calculate this value
    .Take(() => model.ResultsPerPage)
    .ToList();
```

Which allows Entity Framework to know that these are variables and that the generated SQL should be parametrized, which in turn allows the execution plan to be reused.

We have some code in our application that uses variables in the same way, but we must build the Expression at runtime as the type is not known in advance.

Here is what it used to look like:

```
var convertedId = typeof(T).GetConvertedIdValue(id);
var prop = GetIdProperty(typeof(T));

var itemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
    (
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(
            itemParameter,
            prop.Name
            ),
        Expression.Constant(convertedId)
        ),
    new[] { itemParameter }
    );

return Get<T>().Where(whereExpression);
```

The problem is that using `Expression.Constant(convertedId)` causes a constant to be inserted in to the generated SQL. This causes the SQL to change for every new item you look up, which stops any execution plan caching:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = 1234
```

and:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = 1235
```

and:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = 1236
```

The question then, is **How can you use Expression building in such a way as to force the parametrization of the generated SQL?** The `() => convertedId` syntax will not work. I have answered this below.

Comment: I don't get it, what's the question here?

Comment: The question was how to convert the code above to generate parametrized SQL when using Expression.Constant, as the `() => convertedId` syntax doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the main post to explicitly include the question.

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of trial and error, we found you can still force Entity Framework to recognise `convertedId` as a parameter by slightly changing how we pass it in:

```
....

var convObj = new
{
    id = convertedId
};
var rightExp = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(convObj), "id"), convertedId.GetType());

var whereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
    (
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(
            itemParameter,
            prop.Name
            ),
        rightExp
        ),
    new[] { itemParameter }
    );

return Get<T>().Where(whereExpression);
```

Which causes the generated SQL to use the same parameter (and code) for any given id:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
```

The query in question that we were dealing with takes a long time to generate the execution plan, so we saw a significant decrease in execution time for accessing new IDs (from 3~4 seconds down to ~300 milliseconds)

Comment: That is correct, the skip/take example is just a simpler way to highlight the underlying problem of generated SQL using constant values instead of parametrized ones.

Answer (score 2):

Let me recap.

You are building `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` like this

```
var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
var left = Expression.Property(item, idPropertyName);
Expression right = ...;
var body = Expression.Equal(left, right);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, item);
```

and the question is what should be used for `right` in order to make EF not treating it as a constant.

Apparently primitive value like

```
var right = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(convertedId), left.Type);
```

doesn't work, so the solution is to provide a **property of some class instance**.  You solved it by using anonymous type, but of course there are many other ways to do that.

For instance, using a closure (like it would have been if you were not creating the expression manually)

```
Expression<Func<object>> closure = () => convertedId;
var right = Expresion.Convert(closure.Body, left.Type);
```

or `Tuple<T>` instance (a bit verbose, but eliminates `Expression.Convert`)

```
var tuple = Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(Tuple<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type), convertedId);
var right = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(tuple), "Item1");
```

etc.

Comment: Nice! I like the closure solution very much