# Generic Keys On Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm bouncing between these two errors trying to generic out some Entity code shared by about 50 classes.

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
>
> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TKey' and 'TKey'

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TKey> : BaseRepository
    where TEntity : KeyedBaseModel<TEntity, TKey>
{
    public BaseRepository(MyProjectContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    protected MyProjectContext Context { get; set; }
    
    public async Task<TEntity> SelectById(TKey id)
    {
        return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
    }
}
```

The issue exists here:

```
s => s.Id == id
```

If I use == I get an error for objects that use a Guid as a primary key, and if I use...

```
s => s.Id.Equals(id)
```

I get an error that Entity cannot create a constant value of type System.Object.

Comment: Using find() does fix my issue for this, but I'm interested in something that allows lambdas used.

Comment: If you use `s.Id.Equals` it won't work with Entity Framework, since the resulting expression would be casting/converting `s.Id` to an "constant object" (`Expression.Constant`) and Entity Framework cannot work with that. On the other hand `s.Id == id` won't even compile since the C# compiler doesn't know what to do with the equals operator: Should it attempt to discover an overloaded `==` and fail at runtime? Should it box whatever `TKey` type is and use reference comparison?

Comment: By the way, I think you can bypass the compiler if you *write your own predicate expression* using a combination of `Expression.Equals`, `Expression.Parameter`, `Expression.Property` and `Expression.Constant`. Something like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977908/creating-a-linq-expression-where-parameter-equals-object)

Comment: `s.Id.Equals(id)` will not work with Entity Framework and the other method won't work because you cannot constrain `TKey` to a type that will work with it. With this set up, `TKey` could be any complex type.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you will want something like

```
public class KeyedBaseModel<TEntity, TKey>
{
    public static readonly Type EntityType = typeof(TEntity);
    public static readonly Type KeyType = typeof(TKey);
    public static readonly PropertyInfo KeyProperty = EntityType.GetProperty(nameof(Id), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> IdEquals(TKey key)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(EntityType, "x"); // x => 
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, KeyProperty); // x => x.Id
        var constant = Expression.Constant(key, KeyType); // id
        var equal = Expression.Equal(property, constant); // x => x.Id == id

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equal, parameter);
    }      

    public TKey Id { get; protected set; }
}
```

to be used in your repository like this

```
    public async Task<TEntity> SelectById(TKey id)
    {
        var idEquals = KeyedBaseModel<TEntity, TKey>.IdEquals(id);
        return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(idEquals);
    }
```

This works as far as I've tested, but *I don't like this design* (you may have some legitimate reasons of course)

I would just stick with a `Guid` as a key and convert `KeyedBaseModel` to a single parameter generic type or even a non generic base entity type.

**EDIT**
I've just tried this in *Entitty Framework Core* (RC 2) and it works

```
public async Task<TEntity> SelectById(TKey id)
{
    return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

Comment: Building your own expression piece by piece, that's fun... I agree this is a _really_ nasty way to do this, but it may be the only way. I guess I'll stick to find and at worse move to two hard-typed KeyedBaseModels, one for Guid and one for int. If no one else figures out something a bit more practical I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by adding `IEquatable<TKey>` constraint to `TKey`.

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity, TKey> : BaseRepository
   where TEntity : KeyedBaseModel<TEntity, TKey>
   where TKey : IEquatable<TKey> // I've added this line
{
    ...
}
```

So why this code is working?

Before adding `IEquatable<TKey>` constraint, `s => s.Id.Equals(id)` expression use `System.ValueType.Equals` method.

After adding `IEquatable<TKey>` constraint, `s => s.Id.Equals(id)` expression will be starting to use `System.IEquatable<T>.Equals` method, and i think EF doesn't have any problem with this.

*I've tested with the EntityFramework 6.2.0 (.NET Framework)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try use

```
Type t=typeof(Tkey);
Func<TEntity, bool> predicate=s=>s.Id==id;
if(t==typeof(Guid))
{
   predicate=s=>s.Id.Equals(id);
}
return await Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
```